# What is a mechanism to manage database tables with a large number of columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which currently has more than 300 different columns. These columns logically have different sources - some are survey information, some are statistically computed, some are personal information. Is there a mechanism in MySQL to work with separate groups of columns as with an independent table (i.e. to have indices applied to a group, have a separate name for a group...) but still to keep them in one table for consistency?

Thanks,
Vladimir

Comment: There is a mechanism. It's called good design, aka normalisation.

Comment: for consistency? yipes.  please normalize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are those 300 columns related to each other? When a task is called, are all of those 300 columns needed? Chances are, they are not. If not then normalize them to 3rd normal form and bind up the ones that are related. Meaning create a primary key for those separate tables and link them to new tables, using foreign keys, which holds the related columns.

Answer (score 0):

Better split the table in multiple tables. If you want to get all 300 columns in 1 object then you can always create a view over these tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to keep them in one table and distinguish columns you can use COMMENT

```
ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE `id` `id` INT( 11 ) COMMENT 'group1'
```

This should allow you to get column names with certain comment string

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'myschema' AND table_name = 'user' AND column_comment = 'group1'
```